# JSONWEBTOKEN - NODE JS - React JS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

```
const authuser = async (req,res,next)=>{
 const {token} = req.params;
 if (token) {
        
        const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./utils/keys/public.pem');
        const {usuario,estado,id,activado} = jwt.verify(token,publicKey);
        res.json({datosUsers : {usuario,estado,id,activado}});
        if(jwt.TokenExpiredError){
                res.send({message:"TokenExpired"})
        }
    
 }else {
        console.log("NO TOKEN")
        res.send({message:"Error en Verificacion de TOKEN"});
 }
/** jwt.TokenExpired tira un error que tendria que mostrar para cerrar la session. */

}
```

Hola! Mi problema el dia de hoy es el siguiente, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando este el TokenExpired, el back le responda al front un mensaje o un dato que este token esta vencido y asi poder cerrar el login automaticamente, o si quiero, renovar ese token automaticamente.

**Este es el error que me tira en la linea que quiero verifcar el jwt.TokenExpiredError. que vale aclarar es una clase de jwt**

```
(node:15692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)       
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at authuser (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\routes\auth.js:42:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\guido\Desktop\Proyectos\reactproyectos\comercioback\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(node:15692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 
1)
(node:15692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque antes de enviar el message de `TokenExpired`, estas enviando otra cosa:

```
res.json({datosUsers : {usuario,estado,id,activado}});
```

Cuando envias dos veces una respuesta es cuando se registra este error.

Según esta el metodo en el front se va a recibir `datosUsers` como respuesta ya que es lo primero que se envía, e ignorará la segunda respuesta que envías con el `message`

Podrías hacerlo así para que no suceda esto:

```
const authuser = async (req,res,next)=>{
 const {token} = req.params;
 if (token) {
        
        const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./utils/keys/public.pem');
        const {usuario,estado,id,activado} = jwt.verify(token,publicKey);
        if(jwt.TokenExpiredError){
                res.send({message:"TokenExpired"})
        }else{
               res.json({datosUsers : {usuario,estado,id,activado}});
        }
    
 }else {
        console.log("NO TOKEN")
        res.send({message:"Error en Verificacion de TOKEN"});
 }
/** jwt.TokenExpired tira un error que tendria que mostrar para cerrar la session. */

}
```

De este modo si el token no esta expirado enviará el `datosUsers`, si esta expirado enviará el `message`.

Comment: Buenisimo, lo acabo de probar y corre barbaro, gracias por la ayuda!!